# ReactFX: can't build EventStream from DoubleProperty

Tags: javafx, reactfx

I'm trying to make an `EventStream` from a `DoubleProperty` in ReactFX (I've tried both 2.0M5 and 1.4.1 stable). I constantly get this error from IntelliJ:

[image: Incompatible Type Error]

I've tried using the sample code from the wiki:

```
Circle streamCircle = new Circle();
EventStream<Double> widthValues = EventStreams.nonNullValuesOf(streamCircle.radiusProperty());
```

...and I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type does `supportLevel` have?

Comment: It is a `SimpleIntegerProperty` which doesn't do anything particularly exciting or special. The image I put there primarily to show the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoubleProperty`, `IntegerProperty` and similar properties implement `ObservableValue<Number>`, not `ObservableValue<Double>`, `ObservableValue<Integer>`, ect.

You could use `asObject` for conversion to such a type:

```
EventStream<Double> widthValues = EventStreams.nonNullValuesOf(streamCircle.radiusProperty().asObject());
```

But if I correctly understand what `nonNullValuesOf` is supposed to do, you should replace this by `EventStreams.valuesOf`, since a `DoubleProperty` *never* contains `null` as value.

Comment: That appears to have fixed it. Now if I could just get it to let me combine those streams...